# Extra space below table when td max-width is set

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have table in my website and I'm trying to get it scale nicely to fit for PC screen and also in smartphone screen. So everything goes well until I set max-width to 110px for one td. When I set max-width to td, extra space appears below the table. So the table will not take that extra space it just appears below table and it isn't table's margin.

```css
.logos {
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
}

.trackname {
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 110px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.tracks {
  width: 100%;
}

tr {
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: #383838;
}

.buttons {
  width: 115px;
}
#container {
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    background-color: #000000;
    height: calc(100vh - 200px);
}
.cont{
    display: grid;

}
.innerbox {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 15px 0 0 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
.box-style {
    padding: 20px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #242021;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id='body-content' class="col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
    <div id="container" class="cont">
        <div class="innerbox">
            <div class="box-style">
<table class="tracks list-group">
  <thead>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let track of tracklist; let i = index" class="list-group-item tablerow">
      <td class="logo">
        <div class="logos">
          <img *ngIf="track.Type == 1" src="assets/logo.png" width="30" align="left">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="trackname">
        <div>
          {{track.Name}}
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="buttons">
          <div class="btn-group" role="group">
            <button type="button" class="trackbuttons btn btn-info glyphicon glyphicon-align-center" ></button>
            <button type="button" class="trackbuttons btn btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need that max-width for that trackname to get table to fit into smartphone screen. If there is no max-width set the table will be partly hidden because table stop to shrink in certain width (when one word doesn't fit into column).

So can I block somehow that extra space to appear or can I manage somehow table to shrink more and more without td max-width.

In my further test I notice that cont-class display: grid; affect that will there be that extra space under the table. But I must set that because otherwise my style got broken.

Here you can see how there is extra space. Notice position of scrollbar.

[image: Extra space when table is wider]

Here you can see how all seems fine when I narrow screen to fit 360px. Notice scrollbar position.

[image]

So my ges is that somehow trackname text will take that space even it will be fit smaller space.

Comment: its hard to visualize your problem, do you just want to resize the table or one of the divs when its a smartphone screensize?

Comment: can you create a [**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/) or insert a code snippet here and share link here. Because I tried your code in jsfiddle but I couldn't find out where you getting that extra space.

Comment: [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/AchyuthL/uuyhyaqg/) what I have tried to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I add later example to jsfiddle if my new information is not enough.